# find out the image if its already optimized

Tags: image, optimization

I was wondering is there any way to skip the file if its already optimized.

I am using following command to run the optimization for PNG images:

```
find '*.png' -print0 | xargs optipng  -nc -nb -o5 -quiet -preserve  -dir ~/images/output -log ~/optpng.log
```

Its taking long time to process the since the image directory has thousands  of images.

Please suggest me a solutions.

Comment: You can specify some sort of size-to-resolution ratio. So, for every image, you can check its size and resolution, and decide whether you need to optimize this image or not.

Comment: But My image directory has different  size of images, like  Bread crumbs, borders, background etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -name "*png" -type f |while read FILE
do 
    echo $FILE
    BASEFILE=$(basename $FILE)
    optipng $FILE > /tmp/$$.out
    TEST=$(cat /tmp/$$.out |grep "optimized" |wc -l)
    if [ $TEST -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "$BASEFILE is already optimized"
    else 
        echo "$BASEFILE NOT is already optimized"
        cp $BASEFILE  ~/destination_dir
    fi  

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing them in parallel (say 4 at a time in parallel with `-P 4`) and not invoking a new process for every file (by doing say 8 images per `optipng` process) if you have a multi-core machine:

```
find ... | xargs -n 8 -P 4 optipng ...
```

Or, you could use **GNU Parallel**.

Comment: sorry, I cant use mtime, I want it be configured it as a part of  jenkins job

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Jenkins at all. Maybe one option would be to put a tiny note in the image's "Comment" section using `jhead` or `ImageMagick` as you optimise each image and then check the comment before optimising again. Or keep a record of the MD5 checksums of all optimised images.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable reply, btw i have figure out how to handle already optimized image